# Open DB with FMDB in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite, fmdb

i would like to open an existing Database with `FMDB`. The DB should be a `sqlite` Database with the ending `.db`.

My Code is: 
static let shared: DBManager = DBManager()

```
let databaseFileName = "/mydb.db"

var pathToDatabase: String!

var pathNSURL: NSURL!

var database: FMDatabase!


override init() {
    super.init()

    let documentsDirectory = (NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] as NSString) as String

    let zwerg = documentsDirectory + databaseFileName

    let pathNSURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: zwerg)

    let pathString = documentsDirectory + databaseFileName

    pathToDatabase = pathNSURL.path
    print(pathToDatabase)
}


func firstQuestion() -> Bool {
    if openDatabase(){
        let query = "SELECT * FROM movie"

        do {
            let result = try database.executeQuery(query, values: nil)
            print(result)
        }
        catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        database.close()
        return true
    }
    return false
}

func openDatabase() -> Bool {
    if database == nil {
        print(FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: pathToDatabase))
        if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: pathToDatabase) {
            print("Database set new path -> File exists")
            database = FMDatabase(path: pathToDatabase)
        }
    }

    if database != nil {
        print("Database != nil")
        if database.open() {
            print("Database is open in != nil")
            return true
        }
    }

    return false
}
```

Im calling the Method firstQuestion() from a VC:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    print(DBManager.shared.firstQuestion())
}
```

My Problem is that the fileExists-Method always returns false. The Filename is correct. This is my first Project with a database in swift, so perhaps i made a stupid mistake... Any suggestions?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
let fileManager = FileManager.default
let docURL = fileManager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!

let databaseURL = docURL.appendingPathComponent("databaseNaeme.db")
```

and initialize database as:

```
database = FMDatabase(path: databaseURL.absoluteString)
```

Comment: This was the path: file:///Users/OverBurned/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B5EAE004-A036-4BD5-A692-C25EF3875D25/data/Containers/Data/Application/3BC1CBA7-48E1-4A17-A456-108667E7F773/Documents/mydb.db But it was not the solution Thanks anyway

Comment: with your second solution i get this error message: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: I used your updated method. Furthermore I am now opening the DB directly in FirstQuestion() and doing the initialize in the init method. So that i don't need the fileExists Method. The DB inside the project contains the table movies. But if i try the query "Select * FROM movies" he says: "DB Error: 1 "no such table: movies". Any Idea?

Comment: This error message makes so much sense.... I looked into the Xcode simulator and the DB exists but is empty. How can i add an existing DB with data to the Project?

Comment: What do you mean how to add existing DB with data?

You can just copy your db to the project and then you'll need to update path to it to initialize FMDB object.

Comment: I copied the DB into the project. It should be there. I don't know what is wrong....